# asp.net repeater use template in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, templates, repeater

I'm changing an ASP.Net list page using a repeater to have in-line editing. What I'm trying to do is create the template for the edit inside the control (so that I can databind drop-downs) then add a JavaScript click event to the row that will replace the row with a copy of the template and fill in the fields from the original bound row.

This fiddle shows what I'm after:
http://jsfiddle.net/AsciiSmoke/U3z4s/1/

I can obviously code this in pure JavaScript but I figured that using the template would give me the binding and make it easier for the other devs here to update.

Cheers,
AsciiSmoke

Code from JSFiddle

> ```
> This
> <br>
> <table>
> <tr>
>     <td>Field 1</td>
>     <td>Field 2</td>
>     <td>Field 3</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>     <td>Value 1</td>
>     <td>Value 2</td>
>     <td>Value 3</td>
> </tr> </table> <br>Becomes <br> <table>
> <tr>
>     <td>Field 1</td>
>     <td>Field 2</td>
>     <td>Field 3</td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>     <td>
>         <input value="Value 1">
>     </td>
>     <td>
>         <input value="Value 2">
>     </td>
>     <td>
>         <select>
>             <option>value 3</option>
>             <option>value 4</option>
>             <option>value 5</option>
>         </select>
>     </td>
> </tr>
> </table>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need a template. All you need to do is hide the form fields in each cell, then on click hide the text and show the form fields.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935361/on-click-make-html-displayfor-an-editable-text-field/23935760#23935760) is related and/or a duplicate of what you are looking for.

**Edit #1:** An alternative is to encapsulate the "template" for all the form fields in a SCRIPT tag:

```
<tr>
    <td>Field 1</td>
    <td>Field 2</td>
    <td>
        Field 3
        <script type="text/html">
            <td>
                <input value="Value 1">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input value="Value 2">
            </td>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <option>value 3</option>
                    <option>value 4</option>
                    <option>value 5</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
```

That way the form fields exist as String data in each row, which is much lighter memory wise than the DOM tree. You need only look for the first `script[type=text/html]` inside the `tr` tag to find the template. The problem then becomes how you update the template with the changed values. You may have to go the route of a [JavaScript template engine](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/) and keep the relevant data serialized as JSON in an HTML5 data-* attribute:

```
<tr data-values='{ "foo": "bar", ... }'>
    <td>Field 1</td>
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, I had considered loading it in with the inputs hidden. Unfortunately we don't want to use paging and there's a chance there could be a lot of fields. I don't really want the code / dom to be any bigger than necessary.

We're also stuck in WebForms so any Razor tricks are out of reach ;o(

Comment: Thanks Greg, I think I'm going to use the JsRender template engine like you suggest. Maybe JsViews if it's up to it.